# js классы и наследование

Tags: javascript, классы

Прошу помочь
Создать класс Animal c методом makeVoice(), создать два класса наследника от Animal, такие как Cat и Dog, переопределить этот метод. Затем продемонстрировать как работает
полиморфизм в вашем понимании.

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/119265

Comment: `2 + 2 = 4`, `'2' + '2' = '22'` — один оператор, работает и с числами, и со строками. Полиморфизм) Если и у собаки, и у кота есть одинаковые методы makeVoice, делающие немного разные вещи - тоже полиморфизм (т.е. к экземплярам разных классов можно обращаться через одинаковый интерфейс).